# Facing error : Cannot create symbolic link

Tags: openssl, pem, csr

I m trying to install **openSSL** but its giving me error while extracting **openssl-1.0.1g.tar**:

Error:

```
D:\openssl-1.0.1g.tar_3: Cannot create symbolic link D:\openssl-1.0.1g\apps\md4.c     
A required privilege is not held by the client. !
```

Actually I am trying to generate CSR/PEM encoded Certificate request file. So for that I need to install openSSL but its giving me this error while extracting. Can anyone guide me in a right direction.

Comment: Are you installing or generating the CSR?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the similar issue (for a different `.tar` file)

Comment: The archive containing the OpenSSL source code contains symlinks pointing to nonexistent files. On Linux/Unix, those broken symlinks are fixed by the `config` script later, but on Windows it seems most (all) unpackers can't handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extracting tarball with the source code of OpenSSL you should use installer with precompiled binaries from [OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) project.

Comment: This is not a good solution. First source is more secure than binary. Second OpenSLL-Win32 comes with release builds of the DLLs only, I have not seen debug DLLs included.

Comment: @WernerHenze I fully agree with your first point. As far as your second point is concerned OP did not mention debugging at all. He just needed to generate CSR so IMO compiling OpenSSL from source would be an overkill for him. BTW you can check [my answer in other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34414841/3325704) if you are interested in building OpenSSL from source on Windows platform. It includes step by step guide.