# libeay32.dll has fixed path and generates error on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, openssl

I've compiled `openssl` on drive **J:** using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410711/how-to-build-openssl-in-vs2015-x86cpuid-asm-is-an-empty-file) tutorial and, running our program that loads `libeay32.dll`, I got an error on a Windows Server 2012 64bits:

*"... Insert disk in drive J:..."*

Using a HEX editor, I've seen that `libeay32.dll` contains a fixed path:

*"J:\openssl\src\openssl-1.0.2d-x64\out32dll\libeay32.pdb"*

I've found 2 solutions:

- replacing **J:** with an **X:**
- compiling `openssl` on a drive **C:**

The first solution is unacceptable.
The second one is acceptable but done without knowing the reason.

I can imagine that Windows complains about a missing disk in drive **J:** because **J:** is in the drive list

```
`wmic logicaldisk get caption`
```

and, thus, not if drive **X:** has been specified as it's not in the list.

But why does it not complain if **C:** has been specified and there's no file:
*"**C**:\openssl\src\openssl-1.0.2d-x64\out32dll\libeay32.pdb"* on the PC?

How can I know which file is it trying to access?
I've tried to use `depends22`, `Process Explorer`, `Process Monitor` but I could not see any file access on **J:**.

> edit:
>
> another solution is to replace the complete path with spaces

Comment: I think you could also create a drive mapping that maps ***`J:`*** back to the local filesystem. I think you do it by right clicking ***`My Computer`*** and then ***`Map Drive`***. And another option: [Remove PDB references from released file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11109189).

Comment: *"How can I know which file is it trying to access..."* - [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) should provide the information. The functionality of [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/filemon.aspx) was folded into Process Monitor.